# Using a locally stored Excel file as data source, with updates from remote

Tags: powerapps, data-gateway

I'm new to Powerapps, and am trying to solve this problem:

The app will rely on a locally stored data file. Either based on an Excel file, or a Sharepoint list. That is, the app needs to be able to query this data while offline. But a second requirement is that this data source should be able to update from within the app. Either by polling the master data (in an online Sharepoint solution), or by the remote server pushing data to the clients when it is updated.

What is a good approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand the question correctly, you are looking to create an app that can work offline, but still uses data housed online. Unfortunately, this isn't a scenario supported by PowerApps currently, but the good news is that it is a highly requested feature, and work has been started to enable it in a future iteration of PowerApps.

https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/PowerApps-Ideas/Offline-mode/idi-p/825

Comment: I mean that's sort of what I'm asking. I could also be open to connect to the online data source in less sexy ways. For instance by downloading the data externally to the Powerapp, and then pointing Powerapps to that downloaded datafile. Is that my only option?